# How can I regulate input data from user?

Tags: c

I'd like some assistance with understand how inputting data in a program of C works. So far I'm used the java syntax having the convenient try{}catch(){}; clause but I don't see it anywhere on C (or I haven't found it?).

Assuming I have the following array;

```
float f_array[10];
```

Normally for me to input data I'd either use a scanf(...); or a file which I can read input from, but for the shake of simplicity let's assume I use scanf(...);

And I have the following;

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
    scanf("%f", &f_array[i]);
}
```

Now , my question is how to restrain the user from putting in the input a character or a string or the wrong data type for that matter? Also , should I always try to initialize the array before actually putting values in it?

Comment: Read a string with `%s` instead, validate it and keep asking for a correct input for as long as the provided one is incorrect. "*should I always try to initialize the array before actually putting values in it?*" - no

Comment: @Fureeish After reading a string for example , I have to convert it to float for example , how do I make sure it can be done and will be done ? How to notify me for input mismatch by my hand ?

Comment: You write a function that checks whether or not a string can be converted to a `float`. You're saying that you are coming from Java - you have to write `Float.parseFloat(String s)` yourself, but keep in mind that you have no access to exceptions, so you would like to create another function that firslt *validates* the string (or the substring) in terms of `float` converability

Comment: So I actually need to manually parse the data in my own way but doesn't that raise run-ability concerns in terms of the user actually using a character that is not ASCII (i assume i have to convert the string to ascii then int and then float) ?

Comment: "*but doesn't that raise run-ability concerns*" no. Characters outside of ASCII won't be stored as valid digits. There are extremely unlucky corner cases (though I searched for possibilities and couldn't find any) that a special character from UNICODE might be stored as 2, valid ASCII digits. For now (I am 99% sure that it's impossible to provide such a 'falsely correct' input) focus on reading an input to a `const char*`, validating it and parsing

Comment: You can't stop users hitting keys that you didn't want them to hit.  You have handle the mishit key strokes.  You must check the return value from `scanf()`; you should consider whether you should use `fgets()` to read lines and then `sscanf()` to process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now , my question is how to restrain the user from putting in the input a character or a string or the wrong data type for that matter?

Without dedicated hardware support (say, using a keyboard that does not have letter keys, or some device that gives the user an electric shock to discourage them from hitting the `'A'` key) there is no way to restrain a user from entering unwanted data.

Instead, you need to write your code with the ASSUMPTION that the user will enter invalid or poorly formed data, and cope with that.     It is true that your code is simpler if you can assume an obedient and tractable user who only gives correct input, but the real world isn't like that.

`scanf()` - reading and interpreting data directly from `stdin` doesn't actually work well with such an assumption.   The return value from `scanf()` can give you an indication a problem after the fact (e.g. the return value is number of fields successfully input, or `EOF`).    However, when a problem occurs, `scanf()` handles it in a way you cannot control.  Let's say you code has a

```
scanf("%f", &f_array[i]);
```

and the user hits the `'X'` followed by the `Enter` key.   `scanf()` will recognise the `'X'` character is waiting to be read, and return immediately.  The value it returns will not be `1` (which would indicate success).   Even worse, the `'X'` will be left to be read by a subsequent call of `scanf()` and the same will happen again (unless a different format is specified).   Which means, if you call `scanf()` in a loop this way, the same will happen over and over again.

Some folks will tell you to simply find a way to read and discard the character  `'X'`.    The problem with that approach is that there are MANY ways for the user to enter bad inputs, and you need to account for all of them.    If the user does something you (or your code) doesn't expect, you get problems (e.g. program hanging waiting for the same input repeatedly, input being used as data when it isn't).  You're back where you started.

The more robust approach is to simply read a line of input, and do checks before trying to extract a floating point value from it, such as

```
  char buffer[20];
  int got_one = 0;
  while (!gotone && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL)
  {
       if (check_string(buffer))
       {
            if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f_array[i]) == 1)
            {
                /*  yay - we got a floating point value */

                got_one = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Floating point scanning failed.  Try again\n");
            }
       }
       else
       {
             fprintf(stderr, "Bad data discarded.  Try again\n");
       }
  }
```

Essentially, this provides several hooks so you can check user input in various ways.   If you want to, it can be adapted to discard part of a line, and scan useful data from whatever's left.

The key, however, is that the code does not assume the user is well behaved.   It only attempts to read a floating point value after a gauntlet of checks, and still copes if the reading fails.

The code can also be adapted to deal with users who enter data that overflows the buffer (e.g. entering 30 floating point characters on a single line).  I'll leave that as an exercise.

> Also , should I always try to initialize the array before actually putting values in it?

That depends on the needs of your code, but generally speaking I would not bother.

With approaches like I suggest above, you can avoid a circumstance of using the array (or elements of the array) unless valid data has actually been put into it.

All initialising the array will do is obscure cases where the code doing input (reading from the user) has not properly dealt with bad user input.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `scanf()` returns number of elements successfully read, you can check it:

```
int success = scanf(...);
if (!success) {
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c"):
    // OR while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

There is, however, a complex solution. You don't use `scanf()`, but write a custom input method that processes keystrokes and filters out invalid characters, possibly using `getch()` (Windows/nCurses). Here's a minimized Windows version:

```
void readFloat(float* in){
    int ch, ind = 0;
    char buf[100];
    while (1){
        ch = getch();
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch == '.') {
            buf[ind++] = (char)ch;
            putchar(ch);
        }
        else if (ch == 8) /* Backspace */ {
            printf("\b \b");
            ind --;
        }
    }
    buf[ind] = '\0';
    float ret;
    sscanf(buf, "%f", &ret);
    return ret;
}
```

So a possible result of the code:

User input (key presses): `123aaa.bbb456`
Program filter (displayed on screen): `123.456`
Return value: `(float)123.456`

Answer (score 0):

1. give the user some feedback on a per input basis.
2. process each input and allow user to make corrections as you go.
3. use "atof()" to do the conversion, but it has a couple of quirks:
   it tells you there is an error by returning a value of 0.0
   it stops processing if/when it finds an invalid char and returns what it has up to that point
   eg. 6.35k gives 6.35 -- this usually works out ok; 
   otherwise you have to check for invalid chars yourself.

   try this

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   int main () {
   float f_array[10];
   int   i;
   float input_value;
   char  temp_string[32];

   for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
       printf("input a floating point number: ");
       scanf("%s",&temp_string[0]);
       input_value = atof(temp_string);
       while(input_value == 0.0) {
           printf("%s is not a valid floating point number\n");
           printf("example is 5.6 or 1e32 or 17\n");
           printf("try again - input a floating point number: ");
           scanf("%s",&temp_string[0]);
           input_value = atof(temp_string);
       }
       f_array[i] = input_value;
       printf("String value = %s, Float value = %f\n", temp_string, input_value);
   }
   /* use the data */
   for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
       printf("%f\n",f_array[i]);
       /* do something */
   }
   }
   ```